# Getting an error element not interactable: element has zero size only in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver-io

I have been getting this error only in chrome browser:

```
element not interactable: element has zero size (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.105)
```

when I try to click on `<a href="/cart" class="button--counter header__mini-basket" ...></a>`.

This is the snippet from my DOM:

```
    <nav class="header__navigation">
    <div class="user-section">
    <ul class="user-section__list">
        <li class="user-section__item user-section__item-my-account js-my-account">
            My account<ul class="dropdown dropdown__my-account-desktop">
                <li>
                    <div class="spacer"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="arrow-up"></div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/my-account" role="button" class="my-account__link button button--inverse atm-nav-account" title="My account details">
                    My account details</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/logout" class="logout__link button button--inverse atm-nav-logout" role="button" title="Log out ">
                    Log out</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </li>

        <li class="user-section__item">
            <a href="/wishlist" class="header__my-wishlist-link atm-nav-wishlist" title="Wishlist">
            Wishlist</a>
        </li>

        <li class="user-section__item dropdown">
            <a href="/cart" class="button--counter header__mini-basket" data-toggle="dropdown" data-close-on-bounce="false" data-toggle-status="closed" data-toggle-has-overlay="">
                <span class="counter-bubble">
                    <span class="counter-bubble__quantity">
                        <span class="cart-counter-wrapper" style="display: inline;">
                            <span class="counter-bubble__quantity cart-counter" data-counter-type="cart-counter">1</span>
                        </span>
                        <span data-counter-type="cart-title">
                            My cart</span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </a>


    <div class="my-account__background-overlay js-account-background-overlay display-none"></div>
</div>
</nav>
```

I have tried locating the element in different ways:

```
li.user-section__item a.header__mini-basket
ul.user-section__list a.header__mini-basket
div.user-section a.header__mini-basket
nav.header__navigation a.header__mini-basket
```

but nothing helped.

This is what I have in the test:

```
    clickOnMiniBasketIcon(){
    this.cartIcon.waitForExist(TIMEOUT_5000_MS);
    this.cartIcon.waitForDisplayed(TIMEOUT_5000_MS);
    this.cartIcon.waitForEnabled(TIMEOUT_5000_MS);
    this.cartIcon.scrollIntoView({block: "center"});
    this.cartIcon.waitForClickable({timeout: TIMEOUT_3000_MS});
    this.cartIcon.click();
}
```

I am using webdriverio 5 and cucumber.

Interesting point is that running the test against firefox is passing just fine (headless or non headless version) but in chrome (headless or non headless) I get this error.
Also I have to mention that the test resizes window to mock mobile/responsiveness with the command:
`browser.setWindowSize(300, 700);`

Does anybody have any idea how to resolve this for chrome? Anybody had similar issue?
Any kind of help is very much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try running the test in lower version of chrome? chrome 84 is relatively new.

Comment: The test was passing just fine when the chrome version was 80.xxx (that is on the server in headless mode). Locally I have been looking how to downgrade my chrome browser version and it turns out that it is not that simple or to have 2 different versions of chrome on one machine for that matter (for example version 80.xxx and version 84.xxx).

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment - so this is comment-like

I suspected a Chrome bug at first, but now I think it literally means - you need to check your css - in relation to size zero.
Maybe css is not one of your hobbies (if I'm wrong, write a nice comment and I'll shut up)

Run [validator](https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/)
or/and [css_validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_upload) will write to you if there are any problems, including spelling errors (sometimes it miss something, but very rarely)

If that doesn't help, check the page code in your browser - (tools for developers or similar) it will show you in colors and literally everything related to your css and html.
You are looking for any size zero -`font-size: 0`, `height: 0`,
... also `font: normal normal 0 tahoma, sans-serif` - it goes like this : `font: style variant weight size line-height font-family` but some of values can be omitted... It won't be easy

Probably one of this long list is to blame:

```
<ul class="user-section__list">
<li class="user-section__item dropdown">
<a href="/cart"
class="button--counter header__mini-basket" 
data-toggle="dropdown" 
data-close-on-bounce="false" 
data-toggle-status="closed" 
data-toggle-has-overlay="">
<span class="counter-bubble">
<span class="counter-bubble__quantity">
<span class="cart-counter-wrapper" style="display: inline;">
<span class="counter-bubble__quantity cart-counter" data-counter-type="cart-counter">1</span>         //</span>
<span data-counter-type="cart-title">
My cart</span>           //</span></span></a>
```

---

Hm, I was hoping you will find out due to investigation :)
In your browser right-click menu should be this tool or `alt+command+i` [support](https://support.google.com/displayvideo/answer/6188066?hl=en)
if you make a mess - close with x and open again will return with default look

on top you should have Elements `E` (html), bottom Styles `S` and in the corner strange picture (cubism like Picasso) `P`
in `E` click your tragic `<a>` and read down in `S` - on left is like:
`a{ font-size: 0;` inline on right you have link `https://.../style.css:123` = `address:line` to file containing this ...creature,
but first you can test what exactly is blame - with little checkboxes - disable / enable - play with this sometime it works wonderfully
It `emulates behaviour without this piece`, you may also (hover mouse around, Opera has this under 3 vertical dots) `insert Style Rule` - may help (or not) to find solution...

... your code smells like bootstrap or something else what I don't use.
I don't know how you create css - if after following the above you know exactly what to change/remove/add **just do it**
if you don't know how - let me know... well, we will see

---

**The concern** is that CSS is hereditary

- for some reason these strange properties were used - maybe by mistake, maybe on purpose
- if you change class properties it will affect every element of the class wherever they are
- if you remove a class name from `<a>`, it will lose all properties of that class
- there can always be other, more complicated relationships between elements, such as `.class div.class2 a.class {}`

The least damaging blind solution in this case, is to remove the class name from the `<a>` element, and to add inline patches if necessary...

---

I read once again your question - webdriverio 5 and cucumber - unknown for me..
I think you should read [this](https://webdriver.io/blog/2019/07/11/cucumberjs-v5-released.html#w3c-support)

Comment: Hey, I can see at Styles tab for this element two properties font-size:0, line-height:0 just like you predicted. But I don't know what should I do next to make it work? What should be fixed? Thanks for the reply :) @black-blue

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips. I'll try to make it work with the help of my FE developer colleagues :D. I'm just not sure if I'll be able to do it very soon. If there are going to be questions, I will ask them. But never the less, you deserved bounty points :).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and found a ton of reasons why this can happen in Webdriver.io v4 on NodeJS:

1. You are trying to click on an ID where there are multiple elements with that ID.
2. The DOM element you are trying to click on has zero `width`, `height`, `font-size`, `line-height`, etc.
3. There is something covering the element to be clicked on.
4. It's trying to click on something different than what you think it's trying to click on.

You can cover #2 & #3 by clicking directly in the middle of the thing you expect to click on. Does it work? If you can't click on it in the UI, then webdriver.io/chromeDriver can't click on it either.

In my case, it was #1, but I was duped into thinking everything was fine because I had used JQuery (ie. `$("#myId").length`) & `document.getElementByID("myId")` and there was only a single element. **They lie!** They only expect one thing by that ID so they find the first one and return it. Those two methods will only show one item for a given ID even if there are 50.

To find if there's a second element with the same ID, you need to:

1. Press CTRL-SHIFT-I to open developer tools in Chrome
2. Go to the `Elements` tab.
3. Press CTRL-F to search.
4. Type in your expected Id (ex. "myId") and keep searching to make sure there is only one.